# Scrape tag with same class names

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** this [page](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/airbus-a300b1-f-ocaz-airbus-industrie/ge2430) in order to exercise myself, but I can't figure how to scrape some informations in the upper board like the first flight (here 28 Oct 1972)  the age (1.8 Years here) and the production site (Toulouse TLS)

I found that all these informations are under the same class name = 'dt-td text-bold' in the HTLM code :

```html
<div class="datatable dt-outline dt-bordered dt-striped">
  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td dt-width-50">Manufacturer Serial Number (MSN)</div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold">
      <span id="85bc1a4f36c454ca760e">001</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td">Aircraft Type </div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="text-muted font-xs" style="font-weight: normal">Built as</li>
        <li>Airbus A300B1</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td">First Flight </div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold">28 Oct 1972</div>
  </div>


  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td">Age</div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold">1.8 Years</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td">Test Registration</div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold">F-WUAB</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td">Production Site</div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold"><i class="flag flag-fr" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="France"></i> Toulouse (TLS)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dt-tr">
    <div class="dt-td">Airframe Status</div>
    <div class="dt-td text-bold">

      Broken up Aug 1974 at <abbr title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="<i class=&quot;flag flag-fr&quot; title=&quot;France&quot; data-toggle=&quot;tooltip&quot;></i> Toulouse Blagnac (TLS / LFBO)">TLS</abbr> <br> Preserved
      Munich, Germany as a display at the Deutsches Museum, fuselage section, right hand wing and engine only
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my code until now :

```
import requests 
from requests import get 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


cookies = {
    '_pk_id.1.9f6a': 'cdfa30815216fb89.1624032494',
    '__psuid': '32239860292ef7710798673650201fdb',
    'ps_cc': 'true',
    '_pk_ses.1.9f6a': '^%^2A',
    '_pk_cvar.1.9f6a': 'false',
    'ps_sessid': '4OSWQVY0ta0FHTUH6AEgwZ0FrZ',
}



headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/Airbus/A300-A310',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

   
response = requests.get('https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/airbus-a300b1-f-ocaz-airbus-industrie/ge2430', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, auth=('username', 'password'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())

upper_div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'datatable dt-outline dt-bordered dt-striped')
 
Aircraft_type = []

First_Flight = []
Age = []
    
Production_Site = []

for container in upper_div:       
    
    aircraft_type = container.ul.select("li")[1].text  
    Aircraft_type.append(aircraft_type)
```

I succeed to scrape the aircraft type row, but the others, I can't figure how, any help/explanation would be appreciated. Thx all!

Answer (score 0):

Right, each information is within a `div` with classes `dt-td` and `text-bold`. But let's look this way: for example, "First Flight" is at 3rd row of the table in the mentioned website. "Age" is at 4th row. "Production site" - 6th row.

So, to retrieve "First Flight" you need to select a `text` inside 3rd `div` with classes `dt-td` and `text-bold`. The corresponding code would be:

```py
first_flight = container.select("div.dt-td.text-bold")[2].text
```

Same with age and production site. You just select a different row of the table:

```py
age = container.select("div.dt-td.text-bold")[3].text
```